# Retrieving the Firebase key from onItemClick in FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a Firebase DB which I'm using the `push()` method to add entries to DB, thus generating the random key as a reference for each entry.

In part of the application I'm using a FirebaseListAdapter to populate some DB entries into a list view. Then I'm implementing `setOnItemClickListener` on my list. What I want to do here is to return the reference for each entry I click on.

```
    //Firebase DB setup
    mDatabaseStolen =       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(testing);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            DatabaseReference itemRef = mDatabaseStolen.getRef();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), itemRef.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
```

Push being handled here:

```
 mDatabase.child("testing").push().setValue(newBike);
```

Firebase data:

```
"testing" : {  
 "-KTA7xijNrK1SK98rZns" : {     
  "color" : "Rjfu",      
  "frameSize" : 0,         
  "make" : "Ggg",     
  "other" : "Xhfhf",     
  "stolen" : false
},

"-KTABiJuH2-RXwmp0Rcu" : {   
"color" : "Red",     
"frameSize" : 0,      
"make" : "Test ",      
"other" : "No",      
"stolen" : false
}
```

So when I click on the item in the list, I wish to return the reference `KTA7xijNrK1SK98rZns` or whatever it may be. In the toast in the first code snippet, all I'm returning is the `testing` string in each click the parent reference.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have a `FirebaseListAdapter`. If that is the case, you can get a reference to a specific item at a position with `adapter.getRef()`.

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        DatabaseReference itemRef = adapter.getRef(position);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), itemRef.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using custom arraylist adapter, what should I do to achieve same as above??

Comment: Hi, I used the above code but I got this error `Variable 'adapter' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final` but when I made adapter final I got the error instead `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to DatabaseReference`

Comment: Good catch, the correct method is [`getRef`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java#L95). I updated the code in the answer.