# FirebaseListAdapter on item selected getting id

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I am using a FirebaseListAdapter to store my database info's about a restaurant booking.  Everything works fine here.

Can you help me with the code doing the following:

When clicking on the list view, I will be able to modify the PENDING status to ACCEPTED

My firebase database looks like this:

[Firebase database booking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3NUk.png)

Thank you! :)

Comment: Which parts did you already create? Which part are you stuck on? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to help us help you, and why this is useful.

Comment: I created the part where bookings are displayed on list view via firebase list adapter. I am stuck on modifying the status of an already created booking from my listview

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you have any idea? I tried your answer from  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848072/retrieving-the-firebase-key-from-onitemclick-in-firebaselistadapter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and didn't worked