# Firebase Database populate child data into ListView using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to populate a child data in Firebase Realtime Database into ListView using FirebaseUI.

**My Database structure is like this.**

```
- Personnel
    - 00
       - Name: "Wallace"
       - DOB: "11/21/87"
    - 01
       - Name: "Carl"
       - DOB: "05/14/90"
    - 02
       - Name: "Johnson"
       - DOB: "01/17/89"
```

I currently using this to populate data into ListView

```
mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://my-project-here.firebaseio.com/personnel");
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getActivity(),String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(model);
    }
};
mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

And the list is displayed as: (Yes it's fine but not in my format)

```
 00
----
 01
----
 02
```

**I want them to display the first(or specific) child of every data like this:**

```
 Wallace
---------
 Carl
---------
 Johnson
```

Is there any way to implement to make this working? Thanks!

**Notes**

- This ListView is in Fragment
- My FirebaseUI Database is version 1.0.1 `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tiny Java class to represent your users:

```
public class Personnel {
  public String Name;
  public String DOB;
}
```

And then wire this up to the adapter in your code:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Personnel> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Personnel>(getActivity(),Personnel.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Personnel model, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(model.Name);
    }
};
mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working but I need to change `<String>` to `<Personnel>` instead to make this working.

Comment: Good one, I forgot to modify those. I updated them in my answer too.

Comment: May I ask another question? Does FirebaseUI support get firebase DB data using `onItemClick` and pass them to another activity? Or I need to create a method to get data myself? I currently using [this](https://pastebin.com/A5MBe64N) to pass data.

Comment: Getting the item on click: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848072/retrieving-the-firebase-key-from-onitemclick-in-firebaselistadapter