# FirebaseUI - Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to DatabaseReference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I got `Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to DatabaseReference` error in `onItemClick` for getting Firebase Database Key.

**The code I use to populate ListView from Firebase Database**

```
mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/name/data");
FirebaseListAdapter<Personnel> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Personnel>(getActivity(),Personnel.class,R.layout.layout_items,databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Personnel model, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        textView.setText(model.name);
    }
};
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**onItemClick for the ListView** (modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39855001/))

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        DatabaseReference itemRef = adapter.getItem(position);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), itemRef.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

First I got `Variable 'adapter' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final` error on `adapter` in `adapter.getItem(position);` under `onItemClick`
[image: here]

So I added `final` at `final FirebaseListAdapter<Personnel> adapter...` then this error come up
[image: here]

I have tried declared `adapter` as global but still got the same error. Please let me know how can I fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 DatabaseReference itemRef = adapter.getItem(position);
```

into this:

```
Personnel itemRef = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I didn't expect that. All I need is just create a getter and everything works fine!